# How to change the order of boxplots in ggboxplot?

Tags: r, boxplot, ggpubr

Below is the code I currently have which creates the below graph. I'm instead trying to make a graph where the blue boxplots (pun) are next to each other under the title of 'pun' in the x axis, next to the yellow boxplots 'mv'.

```
ggboxplot(
  d, x = "Condition.Name", y = c("pun", "mv"), 
  merge = TRUE, palette = "jco",
  title = NULL,
  xlab = '',
  ylab = ''
  )
```

[image: Graph]

Comment: Best is to post your data with `dput(data)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `mtcars` because you didn't provide data.  You need to `combine` not `merge` with `ggpubr::ggboxplot`

```r
library(ggpubr)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
ggboxplot(
   mtcars, 
   x = "am", 
   y = c("disp", "hp"),
   combine = TRUE,
   color = c("#0073C2FF", "#EFC000FF", "#0073C2FF", "#EFC000FF"),
   title = NULL,
   ylab = ''
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input. This is close to what I am trying to do, but 'disp' and 'hp' as in your example are contained within the same column in my dataset.

Comment: Please share a sense of your data then with something like `str(my_data)`

Comment: $ Condition.Name       : Factor w/ 2 levels "Breakfast","No Breakfast": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
$ pun                  : int  122 88 108 64 90 78 135 94 69 121 ...                                     
$ mv                   : int  90 61 75 47 101 68 135 64 98 99 ...

Comment: I'm confused `pun` and `mv` are separate integer columns in your data set which is why I chose the `hp` and `disp`

Comment: You are right, my mistake. It works perfectly. Thanks for your help.